# first_value over non null values not working in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run a query on Spark SQL, where I want to fill the missing average_price (NULL) values with the next non null average price

Problem:

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

Result I am getting from my query below

[image]

Here is the query I am using

```
spark.sql(""" 

     select *,

    CASE
        WHEN average_price IS NULL AND store_id = 0 THEN
        
            first_value(average_price, yes) 
                OVER 
                (
                    PARTITION BY product_id
                    ORDER BY cast(purchase_dt as int) asc
                    range between current row and 3 following
                    
                )
                        
        ELSE 0
    END AS new_av_price

    from table
    """)
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried using IGNORE NULLS syntax; see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30789 (I am assuming the 'None' means NULL)

Comment: unfortunately we currently use Spark 2.4 in our company env. It looks like this  was only fixed after 3.2

Comment: I am using spark 3.2.1.. and I still have issue with the same use case..

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your spark-sql version does not support`IGNORE NULLS` syntax; see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30789.

You can go with this:

```
select 
    t1.*, 
    (select min(t2.average_price)
     from Tbl t2 
     where t1.product_id=t2.product_id
      and t2.purchase_dt=(select min(t3.purchase_dt) 
                          from Tbl t3
                          where t3.product_id = t1.product_id
                          and t3.purchase_dt >= t1.purchase_Dt
                          and t3.average_price is not null
                          )
    ) as new_average_price
from Tbl t1
```

or this:

```
select 
    t1.*, 
    t2.average_price
from 
    Tbl t1

    left join
    Tbl t2 
    on t2.product_id = t1.product_id
    and t2.average_price is not null
    and t2.purchase_dt = (select min(t3.purchase_dt)
                                 from Tbl t3
                                 where t3.product_id=t1.product_id
                                 and t3.purchase_dt>=t1.purchase_dt
                                 and t3.average_price is not null)
```

These assume that you have only one row per product_id, purchase_dt. If you can have more than one row, you need to add additional logic to get rid of all but one row.

UPDATE 20220405:
If you can't use a JOIN, but you know that the non-NULL value is only up to 3 rows away, could you use:

```
COALESCE(
     average_price
   , first_value(average_price) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY product_id
                    ORDER BY cast(purchase_dt as int) asc
                    range between 1 following and 1 following
                )
   , first_value(average_price) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY product_id
                    ORDER BY cast(purchase_dt as int) asc
                    range between 2 following and 2 following
                )
   /* , ... */
 
   ) as new_average_price
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid a join since the table has about 120m rows. thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @tinazmu I do have the similar use case where I have to populate some capacity with previous non null value and I tried to use the join query but I have got an exception. "Correlated scalar sub-queries can only be used in a Filter/Aggregate/Project and a few commands". I googled the error and it asks me to use agg functions which you already have in the query (min)

Comment: @sunilkancharlapali, I have adjusted the answer (added MIN()) to get around this. Apparently spark-sql needs to know at 'compile time' that the subquery would return one row only).